# Subalgebra: Non-Degeneracy

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.
Regard the bounded operators $\mathcal{B}:=\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ on $\mathcal{H}$.
Consider a sub-C*-algebra $A\subseteq\mathcal{B}$.

Then I guess it holds:
$$\overline{\mathcal{A}\mathcal{B}}=\mathcal{B}\iff A'=\mathbb{C}1\iff\overline{\mathcal{A}\mathcal{H}}=\mathcal{H}$$
How could I check this?

I was thinking about applying Hilbert-C*-module theory:
Any C*-algebra is prototypically itself a Hilbert-C*-mooule.
In particular, the bounded operators become a Hilbert-C*-module.
However there may be obstacles in Hilbert-C*-modules.

Similar statement: [Wegge-Olsen, Lemma 2.2.1](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/k-theory-and-c-algebras-9780198596943?cc=us&lang=en&)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counter-example to $AB = B \implies A' = \mathbb{C}$, take $A$ to be $\mathbb{C}1$.  For a counter-example to the converse, take $A = K(H)$, the compact operators, which form a norm-closed ideal in $B(H)$.

So the first two properties you listed aren't related by any implications.  The scalars ($\mathbb{C}1$) also give a counter-example for the implication that $AH = H \implies A' = \mathbb{C}$.  So the only implication that might hold is $A' = \mathbb{C} \implies AH$ is dense in $H$.

The property that $A' = \mathbb{C}$ is equivalent to saying that the identity representation of $A$ on $H$ is irreducible (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714758/irreducible-implies-the-commutant-consists-of-multiples-of-identity)), so we must have $\overline{AH} = H$, since $\overline{AH}$ is a nonzero $A$-invariant subspace of $H$.

More generally, a similar argument shows that if $A$ is irreducible, then we even have that $A\xi$ is dense in $H$ for any $\xi \in H$, $\xi \neq 0$.