# Is this a basis for the bounded operators on $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $ L^2=L^2(\mathbb{R}) $. For every pair $ a,b $ of real numbers define the operator $ U_{a,b} $ on $ L^2 $ sending $ \psi \in L^2 $ to $ U_{a,b}\psi $ defined by the equation
$$
[U_{a,b}\psi](x)=e^{ibx}\psi(x+a)
$$
Consider the set of operators
$$
\mathcal{B}:=\{ U_{a,b}:a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
Is $ \mathcal{B} $ a basis for the space of bounded operators on $ L^2 $? They seem linearly independent and it also seems like the span should be a subalgebra at least.
But is the closure of the span of $ \mathcal{B} $ all of the bounded operators on $ L^2 $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that the most appropriate notion for bases in Banach spaces are probably [Schauder bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis). The concept that you are interested in (being linearly independent and spanning a dense subspace) is not enough for this.

Next, as @user940347 noted, it is easy to see that your operators (which are called time-frequency shifts) do not span the space of all bounded operators.

A more interesting question (that you are actually asking) is whether your operators span a **dense** subspace. Then, the next question is which topology or notion of convergence you are interested in.

First, if you are interested in the strong or weak operator topology, then the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem#The_Heisenberg_group) combined with [a version of Schur's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714758/irreducible-implies-the-commutant-consists-of-multiples-of-identity) implies that the commutator of (the closed linear span of) your set $\mathcal{B}$ is $\{\alpha \cdot \mathrm{id} \colon \alpha \in \mathbb{C} \}$, so that the [double commutant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_bicommutant_theorem) shows that the span of $\mathcal{B}$ is dense in the set of all bounded linear operators in the strong and weak operator topology.

Finally, I will show below that

> The span of $\mathcal{B}$ is **not** dense in the set of all bounded linear operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the operator norm.

The proof uses the following notation:

- The set $\mathcal{B}(L^2(\Bbb{R}))$ of all bounded linear operators on $L^2(\Bbb{R})$.
- The shift operator $T_x$ defined by $(T_x f) (y) = f(y-x)$,
- The modulation operator $M_\omega$ defined by $M_\omega f(x) = e^{2\pi i \omega x} f(x)$,
- for any measurable set $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}$ the multiplication operator   $$
    A_\Omega : \quad
    L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}), \quad
    f \mapsto \boldsymbol{1}_\Omega \cdot f.
  $$

Let $V := \overline{\mathrm{span}} \{ T_x M_\omega \colon x,\omega \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$.
In what follows, we show that $A_{[0,1]} \notin V$, showing that the time-frequency operators
$T_x M_\omega$ do not span a dense subspace of $\mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ with respect to the operator norm.
We divide the proof into five steps.

**Step 1:** Given $T \in \mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$, define
$$
  f_T : \quad
  \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty), \quad
  x \mapsto \| T \circ A_{[x,x+1]} \|
  .
$$
Note for $S,T \in \mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ that
$$
  |f_T (x) - f_S(x)|
  \leq \| T \circ A_{[x,x+1]} - S \circ A_{[x,x+1]} \|
  \leq \| T - S \|
  .
$$
In particular, if $\| S_n - T \| \to 0$, then $f_{S_n}\to f_T$, with *uniform* convergence.

**Step 2:** Note that
\begin{align*}
  \bigl(T_x A_{[0,1]} T_{-x} f\bigr) (y)
  & = (A_{[0,1]} T_{-x} f) (y-x) \\
  & = \boldsymbol{1}_{[0,1]} (y-x) \cdot (T_{-x} f) (y-x) \\
  & = \boldsymbol{1}_{[x,x_1]} (y) \cdot f(y) \\
  & = (A_{[x,x+1]} f) (y)
  .
\end{align*}
Hence,
$
  f_T (x)
  = \| T \circ T_x \circ A_{[0,1]} \circ T_{-x} \|
  = \| T \circ T_x \circ A_{[0,1]} \|
  .
$

**Step 3:**
Note for $\varphi : \mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R})) \to [0,\infty), T \mapsto \| T \circ A_{[0,1]} \|$ that
$$
  |\varphi(S) - \varphi(T)|
  \leq \| S \circ A_{[0,1]} - T \circ A_{[0,1]} \|
  \leq \| S - T \|
  ,
$$
so that $\varphi$ is continuous.

**Step 4:**
Consider $T = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j T_{x_j} M_{\omega_j}$ with $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$
and $x_j, \omega_j \in \mathbb{R}$.
Note that
$$
  (M_{\omega_j} T_x f)(y)
  = e^{2 \pi i \omega_j \cdot ((y - x) + x)}
    f(y-x)
  = e^{2 \pi i \omega_j x}
    (T_x M_{\omega_j} f) (y)
    .
$$
Hence, using the identity from Step 2, we see
\begin{align*}
  f_T (x)
  & = \| T \circ T_x \circ A_{[0,1]} \| \\
  & = \bigg\|
        \bigg(
          \sum_{j=1}^n
            a_j \, T_{x_j} M_{\omega_j} T_x
        \bigg)
        \circ A_{[0,1]}
      \bigg\| \\
  & = \bigg\|
        \bigg(
          \sum_{j=1}^n
            a_j
            e^{2 \pi i \omega_j x}
            T_{x_j}
            T_x
            M_{\omega_j}
        \bigg)
        \circ A_{[0,1]}
      \bigg\| \\
  & \overset{(\ast)}{=}
      \bigg\|
        \bigg(
          \sum_{j=1}^n
            a_j
            e^{2 \pi i \omega_j x}
            T_{x_j}
            M_{\omega_j}
        \bigg)
        \circ A_{[0,1]}
      \bigg\| \\
  & = \varphi
      \bigg(
        \sum_{j=1}^n
          a_j
          e^{2 \pi i \omega_j x}
          T_{x_j}
          M_{\omega_j}
      \bigg) ,
\end{align*}
which shows that $f_T$ is continuous.
Here, the step marked with $(\ast)$ used that $T_{x_j} T_x = T_x T_{x_j}$
and that $\| T_x S \| = \| S \|$.

**Step 5:**
Overall, if we had $A_{[0,1]} \in V$, there would be a sequence $(T_m)_{m \in \Bbb{N}}$
of operators as in Step 4 satisfying $\| T_m - A_{[0,1]} \| \to 0$.
By Step 1, this implies $f_{T_m} \to F_{A_{[0,1]}}$, with uniform convergence.
Hence, since Step 4 shows that each $f_{T_m}$ is continuous, so is $f_{A_{[0,1]}}$.
But we have
\begin{align*}
  f_{A_{[0,1]}} (x)
  & = \| A_{[0,1]} \circ A_{[x,x+1]} \|
    = \| A_{[0,1] \cap [x,x+1]} \| \\
  & = \begin{cases}
        0, & \text{if } [0,1] \cap [x,x+1] \text{ is a null-set}, \\
        1, & \text{otherwise},
      \end{cases}
\end{align*}
so that $f_{A_{[0,1]}} (\mathbb{R}) = \{ 0,1 \}$, in contradiction to the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Wow what a great answer thanks so much!

Comment: Hey do you happen to know what $ V $ is? Does it include all trace class operators? all compact operators? just curious

Comment: @Ian: Good question. I have been wondering about that myself, but don't really know what can be said about $V$. Consider, however the operator $T:f \mapsto \langle f,g\rangle h$. I think if e.g. $g=1_{[0,1]}$, then the argument in the proof should show that $f_T$ is discontinuous, and hence $T$ does not belong to $V$, even though $T$ is definitely compact.

Comment: OK cool I'll ask this as a separate MSE post!

Comment: @Ian: My argument from the comment was not correct, I think. It is not obvious to me (probably false) that $f_T$ is discontinuous for the operator I gave in my comment. So the question of compact operators is still open, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

No. All operators in $\mathcal{B}$ and hence finite linear combinations of them map continuous functions on continuous functions. The operator $Tf := f 1_{[0,1]}$ is clearly a bounded linear operator on $L^2$ but it maps continuous functions not necessarily on continuous functions -- hene $T$ is not in the span of $\mathcal{B}$.

The next step would be to ask if your statement is true for the closed linear span. You would then have to clarify w.r.t. what topology (operator norm, weak/strong operator topology).

I think that is wrong as well...